# To achieve 100% completion do I only have to do everything in the Progress section and nothing else?

Tags: far-cry-3

I've completed the story so I'm just going through and doing any remaining tasks.

Mainly my concern is with the loot chests. Although I can see them all on the map now I've bought all the additional treasure maps there are a few I cannot get (locked away in Citra's temple for example).

If I want to get 100% completion on the game (meaning the in game judged 100%, not Xbox / PSN achievements) can I just ignore the loot chests? Is there anything else not covered by the Progress handbook section I need to take into account?

Comment: Sorry, just a quick clarification, you're talking about the in-game achievement list, right? Not the Achievements / Trophies that are from Xbox or PSN?

Comment: Just the in game 100% one. Don't think there's an Xbox achievement for 100%. I just want to look at the stats and say 'yup, I beat that game 100%'

Comment: +1 Good question. I'm not sure. I just got 100% of the trophies for the PS3, and I didn't have to collect all the loot chests (or even all the relics, you just need 60 of those). I would hazard a guess to say you would need to get all of them on the main map at least, which would be an enormous undertaking, Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now finished the game and achieved the 100% completion (as shown in the handbook section frontpage) I can say that no, the Loot is not counted towards full completion of the game.

There is no achievement for gaining 100% (on XBox at least) but nor is there one for collecting all the loot. I thereby declare that loot is just additional 'stuff' for you to collect incase you need to fill your pockets with stuff to sell.

If you don't care about loot then I would also suggest not bothering to buy the loot maps as they just clutter up your map screen for no real game benefit.